# Question incorrecly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion

In question *[Chrome returns valid date for string "FY 2000" instead of invalid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931251/)* I asked why the behavior is broken in Chrome.

But most readers misunderstand that I was asking for, *[Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345)* and *[Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684)*.

I know about Date.parse and detecting invalid dates. But few users think they understood the question correctly and marked it as duplicate.

Comment: You really should try asking some question in C/C++ tags about "why this undefined does not do what I want" :)... And disagreeing with specification of the script does not really help much to your case...

Comment: I find it very ironic that a question about quesitons being marked as duplicates is marked as a duplicate... The other thing is that it is marked as a duplicate of a duplicate - lol -  Is this some SO humor?